# Problems uninstalling cmder

Tags: uninstallation, cmder

As a newbie, I need to uninstall cmder (the command line emulator). I have searched extensively to find a way to do so, to no avail. Some allude to the fact that one should simply delete all files, but if this is the correct approach, how can one be sure that all files have been deleted completely?

For example, I tried this earlier and was left with several mysterious files on my system that couldn't be deleted.

Any help with this is much appreciated. In particular, how has anybody else gone about uninstalling cmder?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the instructions [here](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/787), you need to do the following

- Open cmder and run the following command `cmder.exe /UNREGISTER ALL`.
- Run Regedit.
- Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell, delete cmder folder.
- Go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell, delete cmder folder.

Done!

Comment: If you are getting 'Access Denied' Be sure to have cmder.exe 'run as administrator'

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no folder with the names you specified in the directories you specified. I am using windows 11. @Similoluwa Oluwatomi